# I have two Macs on the same Apple ID. Sharing issue

Tags: imac, sharing, web-browser

When I access the internet on Mac 1, the other Mac (Mac 2) has a extra icon pop up and can see what I access. Both Macs use the same Apple ID and are on the same domain. Two different users are signed on.

For instance, I will go to espn on Mac 1. The person on Mac 2 will have an extra Safari icon pop up. That person could click the icon and see what I am seeing.

How do I stop this?

Comment: Both are running Yosemite

Comment: You can share the same Apple ID for iTunes purchases, but then have different AppleIDs for everything else. This way you can register the other Mac with a different Apple ID in System Settings, while using the same AppleID just with iTunes.

Comment: Could someone with enough rep please edit the title of this post?  A [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) and a [Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) are very different things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called [hand off](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18754?locale=en_GB)

It allows you to continue where you left off in an app on one Device when you are accessing another device.

It works via the AppleID not the local user.

> When your Mac computers and iOS devices are within Bluetooth range of
>   each other (about 33 feet or 10 meters), they can automatically “hand
>   off” what you’re doing from one device to another. For example, you
>   can start writing an email in Mail on your iPhone, then instantly pick
>   up where you left off in Mail on your Mac.
>
> Handoff app icon in Dock Handoff works with several apps that come
>   with OS X Yosemite and iOS 8: Calendar, Contacts, Mail, Maps,
>   Messages, Notes, Phone (iOS only), Reminders, and Safari. It also
>   works with Keynote v6.5, Numbers v3.5, and Pages v5.5 for Mac, and
>   Keynote, Numbers, and Pages v2.5 for iOS. Third-party apps may also
>   work with Handoff.

---

You can turn it off under the General Preference Pane in System Preferences

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot. 
I have been searching for this answer for awhile and this is the first time I posted on a site like this. It is very frustrating to know that it was this simple. I am fairly new with Apple OIS.